# Screen connected to the 'mini-displayport' doesn't work anymore on an Apple Monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, lightdm, nouveau

I am running Ubuntu on a Mac Pro with a Apple monitor. The machine has a GeForce GT 120 (aka GeForce 9500GT). The DVI output is still working, but the screen connected to the 'mini-displayport' doesn't work anymore. Things were working perfect in 11.10. After upgrading to 12.04, X fails to start. I did a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 and initially things seemed to be working, but after a few reboots I got exactly the same errors.

The weird thing is that the errors seem to happen quite randomly. Once in a while, X starts fine and everything is OK. But most of the times, X fails to start. There are two errors that I see in my log files:

- "*Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.*"
- "*Failed to tear down EVO channel*"

Some info about my setup:

- xorg.conf as generated by `nvidia-xconfig`: http://pastebin.com/B12B5R2D
- Xorg.0.log right after the fresh install when OK: http://pastebin.com/nE2y2JBr
- Xorg.0.log little later: X has died after I log out: http://pastebin.com/Ln9itCx4 (error 1)
- Xorg.0.log X fails to start at all on boot: http://pastebin.com/v2yFAL8s (error 2).

Some info about the HW:

```
jeroen@jeroen-ubuntu:~$ jockey-text -l
xorg:nvidia_current - NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (Proprietary, Enabled, In use)
xorg:nvidia_current_updates - NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver (post-release updates) (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)


jeroen@jeroen-ubuntu:~$ lspci | grep VGA
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G96 [GeForce 9500 GT] (rev a1)
jeroen@jeroen-ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G96 [GeForce 9500 GT]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:8a000000-8affffff memory:80000000-87ffffff memory:88000000-89ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:8b000000-8b07ffff
```

Comment: hi - can you post your /etc/X11/xorg.conf file as well please.  thanks.

Comment: Ok done. I ran nvidia-xconfig one more time before pasting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now I am fairly certain that this was in fact a bug in nvidia drivers that has been introduced in 295.40. I resolved my problem by downgrading nvidia-current to version 290 using instructions from here: [How do I downgrade nvidia drivers in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129656/downgrading-nvidia-drivers-in-precise). Everything seems to be running smooth again.