# How do I downgrade nvidia drivers in 12.04?

Tags: nvidia, apt, xorg, dpkg, downgrade

I am experiencing a problem described in [this topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126432/screen-connected-to-the-mini-displayport-doesnt-work-anymore-on-an-apple-moni), which I now suspect is due to a bug in the 295.40 version of the nvidia drivers. Are there any builds available for Ubuntu 12.04 precise based on the 280 or 290 branches that I can use to downgrade?

I had a look at the x-swat ppa but it looks like launchpad removes all old builds when a new one is available?

Comment: [doug](http://askubuntu.com/users/27773/doug) - can you elaborate further on how to do this? I downloaded the `nvidia-graphics-drivers_290.10.orig.tar.gz` file, but inside are .run files. I thought dpkg looks for .deb files? My X server has been crashing regularly with 295.40 and I'm hopeful a downgrade will help, but I'm not sure exactly how.

Comment: Go to where it says: BUILDS: Precise: amd64 i386 and download the binary package (.deb file) for your architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page lists all the precise releases https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers

The earliest one I've tried on 12.04 release  is https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/290.10-0ubuntu2 which I've used on a 32bit install to workaround a restart issue

The 295.40 were to close a security issue though you're free to decide if it matters to you.

To downgrade use sudo dpkg -i packagename

(If you want the .deb, Go to where it says: BUILDS: Precise: amd64 i386 and download the binary package (.deb file) for your architecture.)